# how to search a string for a list of words in groovy

Tags: groovy

What is a good way to search a string for a list of words? (case insensitive)

Example:

```
def s = "This is a test"

def l = ["this", "test"]
```

result can either be true or false but it would be good to get the number of words found and that those words were..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> result can either be true or false but it would be good to get the number of words found and that those words were..

Then you probably want to [`findAll`](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/Collection.html#findAll%28groovy.lang.Closure%29) the words from that list that are contained in the string :D

```
def wordsInString(words, str) {
    def strWords = str.toLowerCase().split(/\s+/)
    words.findAll { it.toLowerCase() in strWords }
}

def s = "This is a test"
assert wordsInString(["this", "test"], s) == ["this", "test"]
assert wordsInString(["that", "test"], s) == ["test"]
assert wordsInString(["that", "nope"], s) == []

// Notice that the method conserves the casing of the words.
assert wordsInString(["THIS", "TesT"], s) == ["THIS", "TesT"]

// And does not match sub-words.
assert wordsInString(["his", "thi"], s) == []
```

And, as lists have [a truth value](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/GROOVY/Groovy+Truth) associated with them, you can use the result directly in a boolean context, like `if (wordsInString(someWords, someString)) { ... }`.

Comment: Didn't know about findAll. Thanks!